# Jquery Grabbing id of a select where there is more than one select with the same class name

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a form that has elements cloned using jquery. So there could multiple <select> with the same class name but different id eg. `<select name="ticket1" id="ticket1" class="ticket">`

The choice from a select shows/hides a `<div id="hide1" class="hide">...</div>`
This jquery code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('select.ticket').change(function(){

    var hideNo=this.id.substr(6);
   console.log('This='+this);    //debug for firebug
   console.log('Id='+hideNo);//debug for firebug
    console.log('Value='+this.value);//debug for firebug
    $('#hide'+hideNo).toggle(this.value == 'child'||this.value == 'youth');
  });
  $(".ticket").change();
});
```

Works for the first id, but not any subsequent ones.

Whay am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Are the clones added after this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the third line in your code above to:

```
$('select.ticket').live("change", function(){
```

Comment: It now works in the head, but not the body! I'd like it in the body as it will be part of a wordpress plugin and I need to be able to change some values...`$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.hide').hide();
      $('.ticket').live('change', function() {
  // Live handler called.
  var hideNo=this.id.substr(6);
 $('#hide'+hideNo).toggle(this.value=='3' || this.value=='2');

});
    
});`Why won't it work in the body?

Comment: Without seeing the order of scripts and markup, I wouldn't have a clue.

Comment: Actually that's helpful-  So its not that that code would only work in the head! Something else must be wrong too!

Answer (score 0):

Either use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) so the event handler works for any elements that match the selector currently or added in the future.

Another option, if you are using the built in [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.  You can use `.clone(true)` to clone any data and events tied to that element.